# Control Jquery Range slider with slick slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slick.js

I have a codepen demo, in which slick slider is moving by dragging the range slider but I want to move it when the user clicks on the next previous button also and on the slider itself. Currently, the movement is only by dragging range slider. Any help would be appreciated.

[Demo link of slick slider with jquery slider](https://codepen.io/piyushwalia/pen/VwKdyoj)

```js
$(function() {
  var $carousel = $(".carousel");
  var slider;
  
  $carousel.slick({
    speed : 300,
    height: 200,
    arrows: true,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    prevArrow: '<div class="slick-prev"><</div>',
    nextArrow: '<div class="slick-next">></div>'
  });
  
  slider = $( ".slider" ).slider({
    min : 0,
    max : 5,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      var slick = $carousel.slick( "getSlick" );
      goTo = ui.value * (slick.slideCount-1) / 5;
     // console.log( goTo );
      $carousel.slick( "goTo", goTo );
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 400px;
  background: black;
}
.slider .ui-slider-handle {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.carousel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-top:50px
}
.carousel .slick-slide {
  height: 200px;
}
.carousel span {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background:blue;
  font-size:30px
}

.slick-prev, .slick-next{
  background:green;
  width:40px;
  float:left;
  height:20px;
  position:absolute;
  left:-50px;
  top:50%
}

.slick-next{
  left:auto;
  right:-50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.8/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.8/slick.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
  <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
</div>
<div class="slider"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the jQuery UI Slider update as the next and prev buttons of the Slick Carousel are clicked, hook to the `afterChange` event of the carousel. This property takes a function which accepts the index of the current slide as the third argument. You can apply this index as the value of the slider in order to update it.

Also note that the range of the slider should only go from `0` to `4` as there are 5 slides. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  var $carousel = $(".carousel");
  var $slider;

  $carousel.slick({
    speed: 300,
    height: 200,
    arrows: true,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    prevArrow: '<div class="slick-prev"><</div>',
    nextArrow: '<div class="slick-next">></div>',
  }).on('afterChange', (e, slick, slide) => {
    $slider.slider('value', slide);
  });

  $slider = $(".slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 4,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      var slick = $carousel.slick("getSlick");
      goTo = ui.value * (slick.slideCount - 1) / 4;
      $carousel.slick("goTo", goTo);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 400px;
  background: black;
}

.slider .ui-slider-handle {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px
}

.carousel .slick-slide {
  height: 50px;
}

.carousel span {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  font-size: 30px
}

.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
  background: green;
  width: 40px;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 50%
}

.slick-next {
  left: auto;
  right: -50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.8/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.8/slick.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
</div>
<div class="slider"></div>
```

Note that I only adjusted the sizing of the carousel in the demo to make the content fit in the snippet better. You don't need to amend the CSS in your production version.

Comment: There is an issue in that if you drag the slider too fast, it jumps back to a lower slide. I think the afterChange effect is kicking in when you move it with the slider, but there is probably no need. Anyway to stop that? Works great if I remove the on('afterChange' but then it does not change when you drag the slides.

Comment: This seems to work. It checks that the slider does not have the class ui-state-active which is applied when dragging, before it does the onChange method: 
 on('afterChange', (e, slick, slide) => {
  if( !$('.ui-slider-handle').hasClass('ui-state-active') )
  {
   $slider.slider('value', slide);
  }
 });